# Как скомилировать такой шаблон

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не пойму как правильно написать `invoke` чтоб компилировалось

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct AA
{
    AA()
    {
        std::cout << "AA::AA()\n";
    }
    ~AA()
    {
        std::cout << "AA::~AA()\n";
    }
    AA(const AA&)
    {
        std::cout << "AA::AA(const AA&)\n";
    }
    
    AA(AA&&)
    {
        std::cout << "AA::AA(AA&&)\n";
    }
    AA& operator = (const AA&)
    {
        std::cout << "AA& AA::operator(const AA&)const\n";
        return *this;
    }
    
    AA& operator = (AA&&)
    {
        std::cout << "AA& AA::operator(AA&&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F func, Args... args)
{
    // Do something before
    func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    // Do something after
}

int main()
{
    AA aa;
    std::function<void(AA&)> ff = [](AA& aa) { std::cout << "&aa=" << &aa << "\n";};
    invoke(std::move(ff), std::move(aa));
}
```

Весь цимес в том что мне передают функтор ff который ожидает неконстантный референс на AA, в точке вызова invoke(...) мне не проблема отдать вледение на AA, но вот компилятор с этим не согласен:

> 2137849079/source.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void invoke(F, Args ...)
> [with F = std::function<void(AA&)>; Args = {AA}]’:
> 2137849079/source.cpp:48:40:   required from here
> 2137849079/source.cpp:40:9: error: no match for call to
> ‘(std::function<void(AA&)>) (AA)’
> func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
> ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
> from 2137849079/source.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:701:5: note: candidate: _Res
> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const
> [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {AA&}] 
> function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:701:5: note:   conversion of
> argument 1 would be ill-formed: 2137849079/source.cpp:40:9: error:
> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘AA&’ to an rvalue of
> type ‘AA’
> func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
> ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*UPD*

Вторая проблема. При таком вызове

```
AA aa;
std::function<void(const AA&)> ff = [](const AA& aaa) { std::cout << "&aaa=" << &aaa << "\n";};
invoke(std::move(ff), aa);
```

где-то вызывается конструктор копирования

```
> AA::AA()
> AA::AA(const AA&)
> &aaa=0x7fff8eb18faf
> AA::~AA()
> AA::~AA()
```

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, главная ваша проблема - что ваша `ff` принимает lvalue, а впихнуть вы ей пытаетесь rvalue.

Вот такое вроде бы сработает так, как вы хотите - нет?

```
template<class F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F func, Args... args)
{
    // Do something before
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Do something after
}

int main()
{
    AA aa;
    std::function<void(AA&&)> ff = [](AA&& aa) { std::cout << "&aa=" << &aa << "\n";};
    invoke(std::move(ff), std::move(aa));
}
```

*"По-моему, так..." (с) Пух**

К вашему *UPD* - зависит от компилятора. VC++ 2019 ничего не копирует...

Comment: Не имею права менять сигнатуру ff и список аргументов, могу только свой invoke имплементировать

Comment: Тогда вы не сможете передать в нее `std::move(aa)`. Вас же не удивляет, что, например, что вы не можете в `f(int&)` передать `f(1)`?...

Answer (score 1):

Собственно проблема в `std::forward`, вы пытаетесь запихнуть T в T&. Лямбда не является шаблонной функцией, поэтому использование `std::forward` является лишним, так как сохранение типа не требуется. Простая передача обеспечит неявное приведение к T&.
Ещё вы используете `std::move`, но при этом принимаете копию в `invoke`. К счастью шаблоны считают && за универсальную ссылку, что обеспечивает принятие любых аргументов без копирования.

```
template<class F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    // Do something before
    func(args...);
    // Do something after
}
```

Также и при добавлении && к шаблонным аргументам, вы всё равно не сможете использовать `std::forward` из-за того, что попытаетесь запихнуть T&& вместо T&. Однако если вы откажетесь от `std::move`, тогда у вас получится, копирования всё ещё не произойдёт.

```
template<class F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    // Do something before
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Do something after
}

int main()
{
    AA aa;
    decltype(auto) ff = [](AA& aa) { std::cout << "&aa=" << &aa << "\n";};
    invoke(ff, aa);
}
```

Всё таки, я больше склоняюсь ко второму варианту, но если у вас есть веская причина использовать `std::move`, то используйте первый.